# Debug logs in developer console?

Tags: developer-console, developer, debug

I am troubleshooting some performance issues with inbound integration to Salesforce. When some data is being sent by external system to Salesforce, the response time of Salesforce to external system is varying.

In an attempt to understand this, I enabled debug logs for the integration user and also enabled debug logs for the apex class that external system is calling in Salesforce.

When the inbound call is happening, I am expecting the developer console to show logs for the user/apex class so that I can check the execution panel to see more details rather than the log in debug logs in set up.

Is there a way to have log appear in developer console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Developer Console, uncheck "Show My Current Logs Only".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is the inbound call authenticated? If so Daniel's answer is correct. If it's a public webservice then you're pretty much out of luck. These days you need to set a specific cookie making the call which isn't an option if you're not in control of the system making the request.

If it's an HTTP request you could route it through a third party (I span up a simple node app on Heroku just to log requests and pass them on) but HTTPS doesn't allow these kind of shenanigans.