# Developer Console Not Showing Debug Logs

Tags: developer-console, debug

**My Question:**
**How are we meant to setup Debug when using the Developer Console Log List (Tab)?**

Previously we never had to setup anything, opening the dev console would setup Debug automatically, and immediately starting showing my logs.

Has Salesforce made some changes to Debug...
It seems like it is not working like it used to...

As per Dan's Answer here [Debug logs in developer console?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/debug-logs-in-developer-console)
If you wanted to view someone else's debug then you would have to do setup.

In 1st org:

We ticked this checkbox so we only can see our logs. We did not manually setup a debug line item. - Console shows nothing!
We unticked the checkbox and it showed our logs, but in another org it did not.

In the 2nd Org

We added a manual debug setup entry and and the logs started showing.

Answer (score 0):

The results were erratic.
So I tried the same in Chrome. And it did not fail.
So we believe the issue is Firefox (Not supported by Salesforce).

Please feel free to comment if you have other scenarios or think the answer is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You have probably exceeded the capacity to store Apexlog, which is 250MB.

To solve this, make an extraction with the data export on the object "Apexlog" and copy it, then with the data import you delete them.

Once you delete it, restart the developer console or session.

1.[image]

2.[image]

Comment: can you please udpate your [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257177/the-best-way-to-enable-a-button-after-the-min-char-requirement-is-met/257185#257185) post? thanks